# What are the differences between collision attack and birthday attack?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, birthday-attack

From my understanding both types of attack, collision and birthday, are based on the principle of two randomly/pseudo-randomly chosen plaintext to hash to the same value. I don't want to launch any biased supposition, but aren't they the same?

From [Collision attack wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) I learned that  *every cryptographic hash function is inherently vulnerable to collisions using a birthday attack* but in the [Birthday attack article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) it is stated that the *attack depends on the higher likelihood of collisions found between random attack attempts and a fixed degree of permutations*, thus birthday attack only has this permutation plus?

Comment: The quote from the second Wikipedia page is not very well-written.  I'm not sure what it is trying to say.

Comment: That was my point, I can't tell the difference from available online sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Collision attacks* are attacks where success is obtained when two values obtained by some process are identical. The term is often used in the context of hashes, since collision-resistance is one of their desirable property.

*Birthday attacks* are collision attacks that work by the effect of chance, with the colliding values obtained by some roughly random process (as in the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Marc Stevens's [Single-block collision for MD5](http://marc-stevens.nl/research/md5-1block-collision) (2012) is an example of collision attack that is not a birthday attack.

Comment: Is it valid to say that because of the "Birthday Problem" a brute force attack on MD5 (which produces a 128 bit hash) would succeed after 2.2 × 10^19 attempts 50% of the time?  According to the probability table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: Yes. In crypto we often use the approximation that a birthday attack on a fair hash of $n$ bits succeeds with odds near $1/2$ after $2^{n/2}$ hashes (if we are able to detect any collision that might occur). $2^{64}$ is 19% lower that the more precise estimate that you quote.